# Is it possible to #await with onMount together

Tags: svelte

I'd like to use convenient `#await` Svelte helper when loading data with `fetch()`.

However, I noticed a warning at onMount tutorial [1]:

> It's recommended to put the fetch in onMount rather than at the top level of the `<script>` because of server-side rendering (SSR).

I don't need SSR, but wanted to try it out. Hovewer, `onMount()` doesn't return a Promise, and I cannot create a Promise that resolves with `onMount()`.

Is it possible to use `onMount()` together with `#await`?

[1] https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the promise at the top level and assign it in `onMount`, to initially show it as loading, it can be initialized to a `Promise` that does not resolve. E.g.

```js
let promise = new Promise(() => {});

onMount(() => {
    promise = (async () => {
      const response = await fetch(...);
      // ...
      return data; 
    })();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I was under impression that `new Promise(() => {})` would resolve immediately, forgot that it needs to call it's first argument.